# $f^{-1}:W(f) \to [1,\infty)$ of $f:[1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto f(x) = x^2-2x+3$

Tags: analysis, functions, inverse-function

Let $f:[1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto f(x) = x^2-2x+3$

How can one find the inverse function $f^{-1}:W(f) \to [1,\infty)?$

Without the interval I know that for $y$ we get $y=1+\sqrt{x-2}, y = 1 - \sqrt{x-2}$ for the inverse function, but I don't know how it's done when an interval is given.

After graphing the function one knows that the codomain $W(f)$ is given by $W(f) = f([1,\infty)) = [2,\infty)$. But how can one show that?

Comment: If $x\geq 1$ then $x^2-2x=x(x-2)\geq (x-2)\geq -1$ so $f(x)\geq 2$. Also, $f(1)=2$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$. Hence, $f([1,\infty[)=[2,\infty[$ by continuity of $f$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first let $f(x)=y$ and solve for $x$ ignoring the range at first:
$$f(x)=x^2-2x+3=(x-1)^2+2=y$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt{y-2}+1$$
We reject the negative sign because if $y=3$ we get $x=0$ in this case, outside the (known) range. Hence $x=\sqrt{y-2}+1$ and the inverse is
$$f^{-1}:[2,\infty)\to[1,\infty),f(x)=1+\sqrt{x-2}$$
where the domain of $f^{-1}$ may be worked out considering that the domain of $\sqrt x$ is $[0,\infty)$.